# Is it possible to use DBIx::Class on a database without relationships?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I'm new to DBIC. I've imported data into a database. It's not possible to create relationships between the tables because, apparently, not all the values in the child table's foreign key column have a corresponding value in the parent table.

So is it possible to still do joins between the tables? I've skimmed through the tutorial and documentation but found nothing that addresses this problem.

Comment: The abbreviation for DBIx::Class is DBIC. DBIx is a whole CPAN namespace containing DBI eXtensions.

Comment: Why doesn't your parent table contain all referenced rows?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. It should. I didn't generate the data and it was imported from files. I did import multiple databases (one for each year) into one giant database. I tacked on a "year" column to each table which I was hoping could be used as part of a multi-column foreign key like so: `ALTER TABLE `ar_disbursements_emp_off` ADD CONSTRAINT `ar_disbursements_emp_off_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`rpt_id`,`lm2_year`) REFERENCES `lm_data` (`rpt_id`,`lm2_year`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Comment: First off, you seem to be really doing the full circle in modern Perl. That's great. :) How large is your database? How many tables? How many different tables? Alexander below is right, you don't need the keys to be in the DB if you know them. But if you've never used DBIC before it's hard work to figure out how to build the relationships yourself. But if you created the DB, you can also add the keys, right? What RDBMS are we talking about? And do you need multiple dbs? What is your goal? Are you doing one-time stuff or are you reimporting old working data into a new app?

Comment: 23 tables totoal. One table has roughly 3 million rows. Most have a lot less. I tried adding the foreign keys but it keeps erroring out after a few seconds I think for the reason stated above. I'm using MySQL. I mostly want to pull data from the database to analyze it. I can get away with doing SQL but I thought it might be good to exercise learn some new skills with Perl (I'm a hobbyist, not a professional programmer). So a lot of this is driven by curiousity more than anything. I want to kick the tires of DBIC to see if I might want to implement in a project I abandoned last year.

Comment: @simbabque You can see the raw data here: https://olms.dol-esa.gov/query/getYearlyData.do

Comment: Ah I remember from a previous question. What do you want to do with it?  How are you going to use it so you need relationships? Maybe show us the SQL for creating the DB.

Comment: I had to write a perl script to import them. The schema for the databases are in text files. And merging all the different databases into a singly database took some custom scripting as well to tack on the year columns. The only reason I need relationships is so I can play around with DBIC on some real world data because, apparently, i can't use DBIC unless foreign key relationships are set up.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course define relationships in your DBIC schema that don't have a matching constraint in the database.
If you use $schema->deploy it will automatically generate constraints for all foreign key columns.

Comment: I'm confused. How will it know which cols are supposed to be foreign keys?

Comment: When you define a belongs_to relationship.